# Static non templated function in templated class

Tags: c++, templates, static

First, I'm not realy having a problem, but I like to keep things as simple as possible.
I'm using a templated class named `Math` and besides a lot of other stuff there are random functions.

Different types of random functions, and a function to set the random seed. So every function except the seed function uses the type `class Real`. But when I want to set the seed I have to pass some random (haha) type to be able to call the function:

```
Math<u32>::SeedRandom(System::time());
```

Again this is not a real problem, but I'm curious if it's possible to get the same result without the need to use the `<u32>`.

Here a snippet from the Math class:

```
template <class Real>
class Math
{
public:
    static void SeedRandom(u32 seed) { srand(seed); }
    static Real UnitRandom() { return (Real)((f64)rand() / (f64)RAND_MAX); }
};
```

btw. `f64` is typedef'd to `double` and `u32` to `unsigned int`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Static functions should be called by `ClassName::FunctionName`. Because `ClassName` is a template, you ***have to*** specify template arguments. Static functions can also be called on an object, i.e. `object.StaticFunctionName`, so if you have an object already, you can avoid specifying template arguments, but in my personal biased opinion calling a static function on an object is ugly.

What I'd do if I were you is to make the function a nonmember one (friend to the template, if needed), in the same namespace as your class.

Comment: Yeah, a singleton object to call that function on would be possible, but in that case it would really be ugly :)
Just wanted to know if there is a way to code it so there's no need for specifying the type.
I tried around a bit and it's possible to call it like this `Math<void*>::SeedRandom((u32)System::time());`. This would at least show, that the type is not used, but it only makes compile time unnecessarily longer, and it's even more ugly then just call with `<sometype>`.

Comment: @v01pe: using `void*` in my perverted biased opinion would in no way imply that the type s not used. IMO, as I have already stated, the freestanding function is the best solution. Freestanding functions do NOT in any way contradict the paradigm of OOP in C++

Answer (score 2):

There's no way to make the function callable as `Math::SeedRandom` (except making `Math` non-templated of course). The best you could do is move `SeedRandom` into a separate, non-templated class or just live with calling it as `Math<whatever>::SeedRandom`.

Comment: I want to keep it in the same class as the random functions, but thanks for pointing out that it's not possible the other way.

Answer (score 0):

I'm highly skeptical of a class called "Math" because I find it difficult to imagine an instance of "Math". From the sounds of it, you may want to use a namespace with some template free functions. That you are having this problem may be a sign that perhaps you shouldn't be doing what you are doing.

C++ is a multi-paradigm language, and as such doesn't force everything to be part of an object, unlike languages like Java.

Comment: The thing is, the class also contains some templated `const`s, that are used inside the functions. Also the function I mentioed above is the only function, that doesn't need the template. I'm aware it's not the best possible way to do this, and I migth refactor it one day, but for now it perfectly serves it's purpose.